# custom aggregation function in dcast

Tags: r, aggregation, reshape2

I have a table need to be reformatted. The table looks like:

```
date   ItemID   NewPrice   Sale Amount
1-1     1         5            3
1-1     2         8            2
1-1     3         3            5
1-2     1         6            4
1-2     3         4            3
1-3     2         7            2
1-3     3         2            1
```

The first table I want to reformulate looks like:

```
date   item_1    item_2    item_3
1-1      3         2         5 
1-2      4         0         3
1-3      0         2         1
```

The item id becomes the column names, and the value is the sale amount. The tricky part is that, for some days, there is no record for some items, just like no item record for item 2 in 1-2. In this case, the sale amount should be fill as 0.

The second table I would like to reformulate looks like:

```
date     item_1     item_2     item_3
1-1        5          8          3
1-2        6          8          4
1-3        6          7          2
```

So the thing I want to do is to use item_id as the column, and the NewPrice as the value, for each date.

The tricky part is that, in each day, there are always some items do not show up, so there is no NewPrice for this item in that day. In this case, the NewPrice should be the last day's NewPrice.

Comment: Have you checked `dcast` from `library(reshape2)` i.e. `dcast(dfN, date~paste0("item_", ItemID), value.var="SaleAmount", fill=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution for the first part:

```
xtabs(`Sale Amount` ~ date + ItemID, DF)
##      ItemID
## date  1 2 3
##   1-1 3 2 5
##   1-2 4 0 3
##   1-3 0 2 1
```

and for the second part we use `na.locf` in zoo with `tapply`.  The `na.rm = FALSE` is in case the first date has an NA.  In that case we just leave it as NA.

```
library(zoo)

na.locf(tapply(DF$NewPrice, DF[c("date", "ItemID")], c), na.rm = FALSE)
##      ItemID
## date  1 2 3
##   1-1 5 8 3
##   1-2 6 8 4
##   1-3 6 7 2
```

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "date   ItemID   NewPrice   'Sale Amount'
1-1     1         5            3
1-1     2         8            2
1-1     3         3            5
1-2     1         6            4
1-2     3         4            3
1-3     2         7            2
1-3     3         2            1"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: That first one is ace, but the second isn't filled like the OP wanted. Tangential question: is there a way to coerce `xtabs`/`table`s to data.frames without getting reshaped to long form?

Comment: what is the last  'c' in the function tapply? is that matching function?

Comment: In this case each group has only one element so we just need to return it back.   `c` with one input (which is the case here) just returns that input.  `identity` could alternately be used but `c` is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

The successor to `reshape2` is `tidyr`, which integrates nicely with `dplyr`. Your first case is pretty simple:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

       # get rid of excess column
df %>% select(-NewPrice) %>% 
    # fix labels so they'll make nice column names
    mutate(ItemID = paste0('item_', ItemID)) %>% 
    # spread from long to wide, filling with 0 instead of NA
    spread(ItemID, Sale.Amount, fill = 0)

#   date item_1 item_2 item_3
# 1  1-1      3      2      5
# 2  1-2      4      0      3
# 3  1-3      0      2      1
```

For the second one, use `fill` explicitly instead of the parameter in `spread`:

```
       # get rid of excess column
df %>% select(-Sale.Amount) %>% 
    # fix labels so they'll make nice column names
    mutate(ItemID = paste0('item_', ItemID)) %>% 
    # spread from long to wide
    spread(ItemID, NewPrice) %>% 
    # fill NA values with previous value
    fill(-date)


#     date item_1 item_2 item_3
# 1    1-1      5      8      3
# 2    1-2      6      8      4
# 3    1-3      6      7      2
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be easily done in a single line using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dfN), date~paste0("item_", ItemID), value.var="Sale.Amount", fill=0)
#   date item_1 item_2 item_3
#1:  1-1      3      2      5
#2:  1-2      4      0      3
#3:  1-3      0      2      1
```

For the second case, we can use `na.locf` to replace the NA values with previous non-NA values (after reshaping to 'wide' with `dcast`).

```
library(zoo)
dcast(setDT(dfN), date~paste0("item_", ItemID), value.var="NewPrice")[, 
          (2:4) := lapply(.SD, na.locf), .SDcols = item_1:item_3][]
#   date item_1 item_2 item_3
#1:  1-1      5      8      3
#2:  1-2      6      8      4
#3:  1-3      6      7      2
```

Comment: have a question, where is your fun.aggregation? If it is not specific, it will use length()....

Comment: @Iserlohn By default, if we don't use fun.aggregate, it does `length`